# How to convert an array of one type to an array of another type in C, types are unknown, size of the types is known

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, size

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to convert an array of type A to an array of type B in C, more precisely, I want to make a function populate which has as input two arrays as well as the sizes of the elements in the array.

```
void populate(void* arr_a, void* arr_b, size_t elsize_a, size_t elsize_b) {
  
  // put elements in arr_b in arr_a

}
```

If you know the types you can do something like this:

```
 uint32_t* populated = (uint32_t*) arr_a;
 unsigned short* original = (unsigned short*) arr_b;

 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
   populated[i] = (uint32_t) original[i];
```

Assume n to be the size of both populated and orignal arrays, and assume both arrays were also allocated using calloc such that there is enough room to house the elements.

So my question is, can I simulate or mimic type parameters in C, such that I can convert an array of one type to an array of another type (the types will always be arithmetic types like int, float, etc.), the sizes of the types are always known, that is, if arr_a should be an array of floats, then elsize_a would be 4 (because a float usually has 4 bytes).

So something like this:

```
uint32_t* populated = ("a pointer of size elsize_a"*) arr_a;
```

Thanks.

## EDIT

A use case would be as follows:

```
int* an_array = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
void* bin = some_binary_data_from_a_file();

populate(an_array, bin, sizeof(int), sizeof(short));
```

but if bin contains floats, you could do this:

```
populate(an_array, bin, sizeof(int), sizeof(float));
```

bin has n elements of some arithmetic type, and I want to cast them to another type, here int. The problem is that bin could be encoded as unsigned shorts one time, but another time as integers. The file itself has a header which says what the encoding is, but it is not safe to assume it is always the same type. I want to avoid a situation like this:

```
int* arr_a = calloc...;

if (encoding(bin) == INT) {
  int* arr_b = (int*) bin;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    arr_a[i] = (int) arr_b[i];
}
if (encoding(bin) == FLOAT) {
  float* arr_b = (float*) bin;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    arr_a[i] = (int) arr_b[i];
}
```

In case a conversion is need from e.g., float to int, it is safe to assume that the floats do not have any decimals.

Comment: Not unless you know the types. Otherwise you can't distinguish between `long->double` and `float->double`, which are very different cases. Trivially easy in C++.

Comment: So I guess my best bet would be to have some enum or object macro's on which I can dispatch (if int32..., if float, if ...) and just manually write the types (in C that is).

Comment: @Plegeus How can you have _arrray_ `arr_a`, yet not know its type?  You mentioned `calloc()`, so it sounds like you are not working with an array, but a _pointer_.  With a pair of `_Generic`, this looks possible in C, yet more info needed.  Perhaps post a more complete example use?

Comment: Ok, so, indeed arr_a was allocated using e.g., calloc(n, sizeof(float)), so indeed, you know that arr_a is a float array. However, I want the populate function to be agnostic to the type in some extent, I will update the post to clarify the situation.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is in general impossible to copy a value from a source array to a destination array without information about the types of the array elements.

Proof: The type of an object determines how its value is encoded in bits and, equivalently, how the bits representing it are interpreted. For example, for a 32-bit binary integer, the value 1 is encoded with the bits (shown in hexadecimal for brevity) 00000001<sub>16</sub>, whereas, for an IEEE-754 binary32 floating-point number, the value is encoded with the bits 3F800000<sub>16</sub>. Therefore, to know what to set the bits to to put the value 1 in a destination element, you must know whether the destination element has type `int` or `float` or something else.

2. The C standard does not provide type information for the elements pointed to by `void *`. `void` is specified to be an incomplete type, and there is no standard feature for querying what type was associated with the address during allocation or prior use.

Therefore, the only way to implement a routine that accepts `void *` for source and destination addresses and copies values between possibly different types at those addresses is to provide the routine with type information. This can be done by hard-coding it into the routine, creating an enumeration of supported types, or other means.

Note that the element size alone is inadequate to convey type information, as both `int` and `float` may be four bytes in size, as one example.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to pass on information about source & destination types.
2. You need to pass the conversion function pointer.

Examples

```
typedef enum
{
    type_int,
    type_char, 
    type_short,
    type_double
}types;

size_t getSize(types type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case type_int:
        return sizeof(int);
        case type_char:
        return sizeof(char);
        case type_short:
        return sizeof(short);
        case type_double:
        return sizeof(double);
    }
}


void *convert(void *dest, void *src, types srct, types destt, size_t size)
{
    char *cdest = dest;
    char *csrc = src;
    size_t destsize = getSize(destt);
    size_t srcsize = getSize(srct);
    if(destt != srct)
    {
        while(size--)
        {
            if(destt == type_double && srct == type_int)
            {
                int s;
                double d;

                memcpy(&s, csrc, srcsize);
                d = (double)s;
                memcpy(cdest, &d, destsize);
                cdest += destsize;
                csrc += srcsize;
            } else if(destt == type_double && srct == type_char)
            {
                /* do similar for all types pairs */
            }
            /* ... */
         
        }
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(dest, src, size * destsize);
    }
    return dest;
}
```

```
void convfunc(void **dest, void **src)
{
    char *cdest = *dest;
    char *csrc = *src;

    int s;
    double d;

    memcpy(&s, csrc, sizeof(s));
    d = (double)s;
    memcpy(cdest, &d, sizeof(d));
    cdest += sizeof(d);
    csrc += sizeof(s);

    *dest = cdest;
    *src = csrc;
}

void *convert(void *dest, void *src, size_t size, void (*cnv)(void **, void **))
{
    void *wrk = dest;
    while(size--)
    {
        cnv(&dest, &src);
    }
    return wrk;
}
```